# Pass Interface object as notification object

Tags: objective-c

I would like to pass interface object as notification argument.

I have an interface like

```
@interface StudentDetails : NSObject
{
 NSMutableArray*   studentList;
 int         grade;
}
@end
```

and i would like to pass object of StudentDetails as notification argument like below:

```
StudentDetails* pInterfaceCommand1 = [[StudentDetails alloc] init];
// student list is initialize to  1,2 & grade is 10
NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:pInterfaceCommand1 forKey:@"aKey"];

    [[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"testNotification" object:nil userInfo:userInfo deliverImmediately:YES];
```

But I am not able to receive the notification in other class.
But when i am posting notification like below, i am able to receive the value 1.

```
NSDictionary* userInfo = @{@"data": @1};
[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"testNotification" object:nil userInfo:userInfo deliverImmediately:YES];
```

Kindly let me know what changes are required.

Comment: You don't receive the notification, or you don't receive the payload?

Comment: HI. 

1. not receiving the notification for below case

StudentDetails* pInterfaceCommand1 = [[StudentDetails alloc] init];
NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:pInterfaceCommand1 forKey:@"aKey"];

    [[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"testNotification" object:nil userInfo:userInfo deliverImmediately:YES];
2. Receiving response for
NSDictionary* userInfo = @{@"data": @1};    .


[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"testNotification" object:nil userInfo:userInfo deliverImmediately:YES];

Comment: Can `StudentDetails` be serialized?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is using `NSDistributedNotificationCenter`, which is unusual. Do you really mean to be sending the notification to a different process? If the object that needs to receive the notification is in the same program, you'd normally use `NSNotificationCenter` instead.

Comment: HI.

thank you for the reply.

I need NSDistributedNotificationCenter, because application is sending notification to different process